# Azure DevOps api to return git tag of the latest commit of a branch in a repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml, git-tag

The following api returns all git tags of a repository:

> [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=5.0-preview.1)

Is there an api to return git tag of the latest commit of a branch in a repository?